# Theme Multisite Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, multisite

Hi there I am wanting to use a different color scheme for individual subsites in my multisite setup in wordpress

There is a couple of options out there that not are straight forward..
I have tried:
https://www.orionorigin.com/tutorials-and-snippets/define-wordpress-color-scheme-set-default-users/ - this only does based on user.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152231/different-back-end-colour-scheme-for-the-different-sites-of-a-multisite - this you have to define all your css.

I want to be able to just call a default color theme based on blog_id. Not sure how to do? thanks

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_admin_color', function( $color_scheme ) {
  if($blog_id == 3) {
    return "light";
  } elseif($blog_id == 7){
    return "midnight";
  } else {
    return "sunrise";
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do you want to apply that colour schemes? Assigning a class to the body and apply rules depending on that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i've done some dirty work added some more styles based on this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152231/different-back-end-colour-scheme-for-the-different-sites-of-a-multisite. CSS can be improved more..but ok for now. It still does not resolve how to return default wordpress admin themes so you do not have to do so much css work..

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_background');
function my_admin_background() {
wp_enqueue_style(
'custom-style',
get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
);
  global $blog_id;
  $color = '';
  if ($blog_id == 7) {
    $color = '#62009a';
    $color2 = '#230037';
    $color3 = '#560088';
    $color4 = '#ffffff';
  } elseif ($blog_id == 3) {
     $color = '#a1c900';
     $color2 = '#627a00';
     $color3 = '#2c3700';
     $color4 = '#ffffff';
  } elseif ($blog_id == 4) {
     $color = '#8c0021';
     $color2 = '#530014';
     $color3 = '#bc002c';
     $color4 = '#ffffff';
  } else {
     $color = '#1d2427';
  }
  $custom_css = "<style> #wpadminbar, #adminmenuwrap,#adminmenu,#adminmenu .wp-submenu,#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul.ab-sub-secondary,#wpadminbar .menupop .ab-sub-wrapper { background: $color!important }
                #wpadminbar:not(.mobile) .ab-top-menu>li:hover>.ab-item, #adminmenu li.wp-has-current-submenu a.wp-has-current-submenu,#adminmenu .wp-has-current-submenu .wp-submenu,#adminmenu li.opensub > a.menu-top,#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul.ab-sub-secondary .ab-submenu { color:$color4; background: $color2 }
                #adminmenu li.menu-top:hover{ background: $color3 }
                #adminmenu .wp-submenu a:hover, #adminmenu a:hover, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:hover, #wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop .ab-sub-secondary>li>a:hover,#wpadminbar .quicklinks .menupop ul li a:focus { color: $color4!important; } </style>";
  wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
```